# Code refactor with promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running the jscpd tool with my code and it detects the following as duplicate code:

```
 dbService.connectDb(commonService.DB_CONFIG.CONNECTIONSTRING, {}).then(() => {
                    return dbService.query(Model, {
                        'name':Name
                    }, {}, {});
                })
         .then(data => dbService.disconnectDb(data))
         .then(data => callback(data))
         .catch((error) => {
          dbService.disconnectDb(error).then(error => {
           console.log(error);
           callback({}, error);
      })
  });
```

The same way I am using for various methods, but the cpd command detects:

```
 .then(data => dbService.disconnectDb(data))
     .then(data => callback(data))
     .catch((error) => {
      dbService.disconnectDb(error).then(error => {
       console.log(error);
       callback({}, error);
  }
```

This as code copied, how can I solve this or improve the code?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: Yes, the title is not meeting the site standard, but why down vote a decent question though?

Comment: @another-guy I didn't downvote it (yet) but what makes a question decent? Isn't the title one of the criteria?

Comment: A question is decent because of many reasons. It's concrete -- how to keep code DRY. It's educating -- I learnt about jscpd. It's clear -- at least to me -- about what's being asked. I agree, that title is one of criteria. However, a new user may easily overlook a requirement that says the title should describe the intent of the code. Also, the title is the hardest to get right. I don't see a point in punishing new users without giving them a chance to fix the issues with their first post.

Comment: You still have a chance to improve the question by showing the full context of the code that you are asking about. (Just make sure that you are only _adding_ code to the question, not modifying any of the existing code you have already posted.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Duplicate code is asking for extraction**

If I understand correctly, you have the same code repeated in several places, which are detected by the tool you're using.

You can always find a way to extract such code into a function/method and invoke if from wherever it's being used.

```
function processPromiseAndDisconnect(promise, callback) {
  promise
    .then(data => dbService.disconnectDb(data))
    .then(data => callback(data))
    .catch((error) => {
      dbService
        .disconnectDb(error)
        .then(error => {
          console.log(error);
          callback({}, error);
        });
    });
}

function consumer() {
  let promiseToProcess = createPromise(...);
  processPromiseAndDisconnect(promiseToProcess, (result, error) => {
    // Do work here...
  });
}
```

**Side note: No need in repeated `.then()`**

```
.then(data => dbService.disconnectDb(data))
.then(data => callback(data))
```

can be united like this:

```
.then(data => {
  dbService.disconnectDb(data);
  callback(data);
})
```

---

**Update 1** Please look at the code below which should be almost a complete example. The `query()` method is the one which does the work using the database open. Notice that `Model` and `Name` may need to be provided from the outside of the function.

```
function consumer() {
  const openDbPromise = connectToDb();
  processPromiseAndDisconnect(query(openDbPromise), (result, error) => {
    // Do work here...
  });
}

function connectToDb() {
  return dbService.connectDb(commonService.DB_CONFIG.CONNECTIONSTRING, {});
}

function query(openDbPromise) {
  return openDbPromise.then(() => dbService.query(Model, {'name': Name }, {}, {}));
}

function processPromiseAndDisconnect(promise, callback) {
  promise
    .then(data => {
      dbService.disconnectDb(data);
      callback(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      dbService
        .disconnectDb(error)
        .then(error => {
          console.log(error);
          callback({}, error);
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: what should be inside the createPromise

Comment: can you modify the answer according to my scenario

Comment: what is createPromise function?

Comment: @Sajeetharan please, see my update. That should give you a better idea I hope. I will not be able to write a complete solution for you, not knowing the complete context.